# Can't find string in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a very simple program to find phrases in text. It works fine when I search for a class or ID. But I can't get it to find specific text. In this example, I want it to see if the website python.org has the word 'python' anywhere on the page.

Oddly it is returning 'python not found'. Appreciate your help with this!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get("https://www.python.org/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

find_python = soup.find_all(string="python")


if find_python:
    print('found python')
else:
    print("python not found")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not getting any results back is because there isn't any element that simply contains the string `python` on that webpage. There are elements that contain the string `Python`, however, and you can see that by running:

```py
soup.find(string="Python")
>>>'Python'
```

If you want to check whether the Python homepage contains the word 'python', which of course it will, you can do:

```py
'python' in str(soup.html)
>>> True
```

Comment: This really helped me vtasca - thanks so much for your assistance!